# generic container for exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

handling exceptions is important for code safety and to prevent undesired conditions as input for subsequent routines/algorithms. On the other hand, tough, filling the code with try/catch/throw statements makes it less readable. Is there any programming technique that helps to avoid mixing exception handling and algorithm-related code?

Thanks,

Comment: Usually, you should only catch an exception if you can handle it (i.e., recover from it). Generally, exceptions are thrown from many more places than they are caught and handled (which is okay, because exceptions should be thrown far less often than not). Can you give an example of a function that you think is "confusing" so that we can give targeted advice? It's kind of hard to say "use exceptions this way" because it really depends on the type of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect Oriented Programming allows you to create advice's on e.g. how to handle exceptions globally.

See [this MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301356.aspx) or this [slideshow](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.lyee-project.soft.iwate-pu.ac.jp/somet_05/PresenSlides/sep28_O.Spincczyk.pdf) for more information.

[AOP using Unity 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/aopusingunity2.aspx) is also a good example.

Comment: AOP cannot handle exceptions.  At best, it can only translate them.

Comment: @Hans - I have never said that AOP can handle exceptions. But, at the same time, it allows you to create a nice and very clear global exception handling mechanism. Have you read the AOP using Unity 2.0 article that I have referenced above? It shows how to use AOP to achieve just that.